# use axis of original plot in \spy plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, spy

I use `\spy` in an plot. This works generally, but I want the axis in my magnification too. I attach a picture to clarify. I do not want to do this with a `\node` and manually calculate and add the axis in the node. I want tikz/pgf to do this calculation for me. The file I get my table from has 4000 entries and I have to do many plots as this, so doing this by hand is not an option. I want `\spy` to "understand" where it spies and then adds this as axis. Searched a lot, not sure if this is possible.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=6, connect spies}]
\begin{axis}[xlabel={x},ylabel={y}, xmin=0, xmax=8.1216, ymin=2.4, ymax=3.4, grid, width=14.5cm, height=7cm]
\begin{scope}
\spy[rectangle, black, width=4cm, height=2.5cm] on (4.26,4.63) in node [fill=white] at (3,1.87);
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{blabla}
\label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Spy just magnifies what is there but there is no axis in the area you are spying on, is there?

Comment: You may draw some gray thin lines that are almost invisible, but become visible in `spy`. Or plot your data two times with magnifying and clipping.

Comment: I don't like the idea of drawing something tiny in order to see it later correct in the maginification. I don't get your second idea. Could you exlpain it in detail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In reply to comment, this is what I said "plotting data two times". I meant no matter how you spy it, sooner or later you will need someone drawing axises and ticks. To do so the straightest way is to call another `axis` environment. Then why not just apply your data the second time?

Maybe you are worrying that there are thousands of entries and copying everything sounds stupid. Unfortunately it is almost impossible to determine whether an entry is visible or not. (see the point and segments at the lower right corner.) My answer copies all entries, so does `\spy`. If this is really an issue, consider to write some *preprocessor* in `python` or something. Or `gnuplot`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \edef\data{}
    \foreach\n in{1,...,100}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{cos(20*\n)*exp(-\n/20)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{sin(20*\n)*exp(-\n/20)}
        \xdef\data{\data(\x,\y)}
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,grid,height=12cm,width=12cm,]
            \addplot coordinates{\data};
        \end{axis}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=-.01,xmax=.01,ymin=-.01,ymax=.01,grid,height=4cm,width=4cm,
            shift={(7.3cm,1.3cm)},axis background/.style={fill=white}]
            \addplot coordinates{\data};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```