# Magnifying a section of a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, magnification

Tried to magnify a part of my graph but I keep getting an error. Not sure where I went wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Error pop up:

> Dimension too large. \pgf@xx \end{loglogaxis}

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines=
{circle, magnification=4, connect spies}]
    \begin{loglogaxis}[x post scale=2, y post scale=1.5,xlabel=Reynolds Number,ylabel=Ohnesorge number, xmin=10^0, xmax=10^5, ymin=10^-3, ymax=10^1, grid=major, grid=minor]
\addlegendentry{1/4 Lift}
 \addplot[color=black, mark=x, only marks] coordinates{
 (6485.41491,   0.003317065)
 (7927.942858,  0.003317065)
 (8663.115504,  0.003317065)
 (9219.462371,  0.003317065)
 (9537.374867,  0.003317065)
 (10491.11235,  0.003317065)
 (11087.19828,  0.003317065)
 (12219.76155,  0.003317065)
};
\addlegendentry{1/2 Lift}
 \addplot[color=yellow, mark=o, only marks] coordinates{
(6556.945221,   0.003317065)
(7868.334265,   0.003317065)
(8663.115504,   0.003317065)
(9187.671122,   0.003317065)
(9120.114717,   0.003317065)
(10443.42548,   0.003317065)
(11683.28421,   0.003317065)
(12875.45607,   0.003317065)

};
\coordinate (spypoint) at (10^4,10^-2);
\coordinate (magnifyglass) at (10^2,10^-1);
    \end{loglogaxis}%
    \spy [blue, size=1.5cm] on (spypoint)
in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\caption{Oh vs Re for straight nozzle}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There used to be similar questions. And I had answered one of them: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220960/use-axis-of-original-plot-in-spy-plot/222205#222205

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `axis cs:` to the coordinates, i.e., write

```
\coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:10^4,10^-2);
\coordinate (magnifyglass) at (axis cs:10^2,10^-1);
```

Without this prefix, tikz tries to locate `spypoint` 10000 cm to the east and 0.01 cm to the north of the origin. With the prefix, tikz transforms the given coordinates in the same way as the coordinates of the plot, here even logarithmically. (cs stands for Coordinate System.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines=
{circle, magnification=4, connect spies}]
    \begin{loglogaxis}[x post scale=2, y post scale=1.5,xlabel=Reynolds Number,ylabel=Ohnesorge number, xmin=10^0, xmax=10^5, ymin=10^-3, ymax=10^1, grid=major, grid=minor]
\addlegendentry{1/4 Lift}
 \addplot[color=black, mark=x, only marks] coordinates{
 (6485.41491,   0.003317065)
 (7927.942858,  0.003317065)
 (8663.115504,  0.003317065)
 (9219.462371,  0.003317065)
 (9537.374867,  0.003317065)
 (10491.11235,  0.003317065)
 (11087.19828,  0.003317065)
 (12219.76155,  0.003317065)
};
\addlegendentry{1/2 Lift}
 \addplot[color=yellow, mark=o, only marks] coordinates{
(6556.945221,   0.003317065)
(7868.334265,   0.003317065)
(8663.115504,   0.003317065)
(9187.671122,   0.003317065)
(9120.114717,   0.003317065)
(10443.42548,   0.003317065)
(11683.28421,   0.003317065)
(12875.45607,   0.003317065)

};
\coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:10^4,10^-2);
\coordinate (magnifyglass) at (axis cs:10^2,10^-1);
    \end{loglogaxis}%
    \spy [blue, size=1.5cm] on (spypoint)
 in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot helped solved it, what did cs axis function do?

Comment: @user127841 The coordinates that you use in the plot obviously are not the coordinates on paper (drawing at 6485 cm in the x-direction and 0.003317065 cm in the y-direction doesn't make sense), but are coordinates in the context of your axes that are rescaled (here even logarithmically). With the prefix `axis cs:` you tell tikz that the coordinates are to be interpreted in the coordinate system (cs) of the axes, not as coordinates of the final picture.